# PHP + MySql + Stored procedure + cursor: don't got any row in result

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, mysqli

I have problem with a stored procedure where i use a cursor, so i made a test code to spot the problem but its still a mystery for me, here is the test codes:

Stored proc. body named 'Test1':

```
SELECT 'ok1';
```

Stored proc. body named 'Test2':

```
DECLARE testCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT 'stuff';
OPEN testCursor;
CLOSE testCursor;
SELECT 'ok2';
```

Php test code:

```
$mysql_obj = new mysqli($sqlserver, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $sqldatabase);

$statement = $mysql_obj->prepare('CALL Test1()');
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->get_result();
if($result === false) die('bad result');
if($result->num_rows === 0) die('row expected');

$row = $result->fetch_row();
if($row === NULL) die('fetch_row error');

echo 'Got: ' . $row[0];
```

Run results the message `"Got: ok1"` as expected, but if i change the call to `Test2` the message will be "row expected".

The really confusing in this problem that in phpmyadmin `CALL Test1();` and the `CALL Test2();` command both results one row with the `"ok1"/"ok2"` value (tested in dbForge Studio Express, it's good too).

What am I missing?

Comment: According to the PHP docs for `mysqli->prepare`, "you should not add a terminating semicolon or \g to the statement".

Comment: True, but it doesn't affect the problem, I just tried and didn't help.

Comment: did you try to just not close the cursor? In oracle you would just do "open testCursor" and leave the stored procdure